# Gmail image proxy

Tags: php, html, gmail, html-email

I'm sending out html emails. One of the png images is not showing up. When I click on the proxy link I get a 404 error, but the actual image exists and can be publicly clicked on. This works fine on my dev server too. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: please provide code. best guess is that your image path is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I've heard reports that having the same image in multiple places can be the cause of this error with the Google proxy. Save your image as a different names and it should show. Silly that you'd want to load 2 images instead of one, but I believe that is the only workaround currently.